# Deploy war file in a grizzly server

Tags: java, war, grizzly, java-war

I have spent a few days on this and I still did not find an answer (i did find questions asking for this)

I am coding with java, using a **grizzly** server (2.3 version) and I've managed to work with many kind of resources (restful classes, java servlets etc).

```
    URI uri = new URI("http://localhost....");
    ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig();
    rc.registerClasses(aResource.class);
    GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri, rc);
```

My goal though, is to load a whole **war** file and not individual classes but i have not find a way to do it.

---

So the question is 'how can i deploy and run a **war** file inside a **grizzly** server?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to deploy WAR files to Grizzly 2.x at this point in time.

Comment: I think that this is a big drawback for grizzly.. Can you recommend any other libraries that are capable to load a war file?

Comment: Outside of a full container and Grizzly 1.9, no.

Comment: By 'other libraries', I mean something like Jetty, which - i think - can support this kind of functionality. Thanks for your help, although it is not what 've i hoped, it is the accepted answer for this question :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Grizzly Javadoc](https://grizzly.java.net/docs/1.9/apidocs/com/sun/grizzly/http/embed/GrizzlyWebServer.html) you do it like this:

### Synchronous Web Server servicing a Servlet

```
    GrizzlyWebServer ws = new GrizzlyWebServer("/var/www");
    try {
        ServletAdapter sa = new ServletAdapter();
        sa.setRootFolder("/Path/To/Exploded/War/File");
        sa.setServlet(new MyServlet());
        ws.addGrizzlyAdapter(sa);
        ws.start();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Something when wrong.
    }
```

However, as you can see, you first have to "explode" the WAR file; i.e. unpack it into the file system.

---

You seem to be using the Jersey `ResourceConfig` class.  To make your approach work, I *think* you would need to do the following:

1. Unpack the WAR file.
2. Create a URLClassloader instance that loads from "/WEB-INF/classes" the JARs etc in "/WEB-INF/lib".
3. Register it by calling `ResourceConfig.setClassLoader`

For the record, classloading from a packed WAR file is more effort, and apparently gives poor performance.  (If you want to see how to do it, Tomcat has this functionality ... disabled by default.)

Comment: Unfortunately this is applicable to an older grizzly version (1.9) and i am using a newer one. But this is on me, since i did not specify what version i use (2.3). I have edited the question. By any chance, do you know how to do this using 2x versions?

Comment: Sorry.  Don't know.  It looks like they decided that running classic servlets on Grizzly was not a feature they wanted to support.  (Grizzly has its own set of APIs that are intended to be used instead of the servlet APIs ...)  You say that it is a "big drawback", but the same logic would say that it is a big drawback that you can't make an espresso with a teapot,

Comment: I think that the "espresso-teapot" is not the best comparison since i am expecting from oranges to produce orange juice, not lemon juice. Grizzly is a good empendedd Java server container that cannot handle the standard file for java Web Applications (WAR), which is kind of weird. Anyway, the outcome in this case was that i was forced to replace Grizzly with Jetty for this specific reason.